# Creating separate pdf file containing the bibliography

Tags: bibliographies

Some grant agencies require separate pdf files for the main proposal and the references. I guess, it is easier to work this way in Word `:-)`

In LaTeX, one can create a single PDF file and then split it later using `pdftk` or other tools. However, is a direct method of creating two separate PDF files: one that contains the main text (with the correct citation information) and the second with all the list of references. I understand that, at the very least this will involve compiling two separate `.tex` files. That is okay. I just don't want to use additional tools (can be tricky to install on all computers of all collaborators, etc.)

Here is a MWE to play with:

```
\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
  @ARTICLE{author,
    title={A sample article},
    author={Random Author},
    journal={Random journal},
    volume = {10},
    year = {2000},
  }
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}
As shown by \citet{author}, using references can be interesting

\newpage
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

Comment: (1) You can do it with one `.tex` file if you rename the first PDF. (2) You could do it, I think, with 3 `.tex` files where 2 are wrappers you compile. (3) You can create a document specific `.bib` using `biber` (whether you use this for compilation or not) and use 2 `.tex` files. (4) You can use 3 `.tex` files all of which you compile, where 2 just include the right pages from the compiled version of the third.

Comment: An MWE would obviously come in handy...

Comment: How about using `\includeonly`? Also, the package `tcolorbox` provides recording macro. I wonder if it can be useful here.

Comment: @cfr: Thanks. I have added a a MWE. I would greatly appreciate if you could expand up on your comments.

Comment: @HarishKumar: `\includeonly` only works with `\chapter`. I am using `article` class. (But I wonder if `memoir` with `article` option will work with `\includeonly`.

Comment: Why not just use `pdfpages` to split the compiled PDF? You just need 2 simple wrapper `.tex` files. You would need to specify the point to split the PDF in the wrappers i.e. it is not entirely automatic. But it has the advantage of simplicity: everyone will easily understand what the wrappers do and how to adjust the code (by changing one number) if the pagination of the article changes.

Comment: @cfr Perhaps that is the simplest method indeed.

Comment: What about the page numbers? You want them to be independent or continuous?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is some acrobatics that uses two `.tex` files. First use `atbegshi` and discard the bibliography and then add it in the second file. The following is named, say `test.tex`

```
\begin{filecontents}{testttt.bib}
  @ARTICLE{author,
    title={A sample article},
    author={Random Author},
    journal={Random journal},
    volume = {10},
    year = {2000},
  }
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{atbegshi}

\begin{document}
As shown by \citet{author}, using references can be interesting

\newpage
\AtBeginShipout{%
\AtBeginShipoutDiscard
}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{testttt}
\end{document}
```

This will not produce the bibliography.

[image]

Now create a new file called `reference.tex` with the following

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\input{test.bbl}     %% watch out for the same name
\end{document}
```

This will give you

[image]

If you want a single `.tex` file, we can complicate things further ;-)  Following is the `test.tex` file that will give you two pdf files -- `test.pdf` having proposal and `reference.pdf` having references.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{reference.tex}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\input{test.bbl}     %% watch out for the same name
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{testttt.bib}
  @ARTICLE{author,
    title={A sample article},
    author={Random Author},
    journal={Random journal},
    volume = {10},
    year = {2000},
  }
\end{filecontents*}

\immediate\write18{pdflatex reference}

\begin{document}
As shown by \citet{author}, using references can be interesting

\newpage
\AtBeginShipout{%
\AtBeginShipoutDiscard
}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{testttt}
\end{document}
```

However, if the page numbers need to be continuous, it is better to use `pdfpages` as suggested by cfr.

Comment: This method works the best for my workflow. Thanks

Comment: @Aditya Glad it worked. You are welcome :)

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps the simplest way is to compile the PDF normally and then use 2 wrappers with `pdfpages` to produce the 2 PDFs. The following assumes that your main article is `main.tex` and so produces `main.pdf` when compiled:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @ARTICLE{author,
    title={A sample article},
    author={Random Author},
    journal={Random journal},
    volume = {10},
    year = {2000},
  }
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{body.tex}
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{pdfpages}
  \begin{document}
  \includepdf[pages=1]{main}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{biblio.tex}
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{pdfpages}
  \begin{document}
  \includepdf[pages=2]{main}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}
As shown by \citet{author}, using references can be interesting

\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}% comment out for continuous numbering
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Here is the body:

[image: body]

and references:

[image: biblio]

Answer (score 1):

Here's the bones of one way, which could be optimized with a simple Makefile.

I would've thought it would work with the `--jobname=` switch, but this seems to make it try to load the new jobname `.aux` file.  So, instead, you can use `--output-directory=` to dump the new file *sans* bibliography there.

```
% filename.tex
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}% <-- to make the command line stuff more readable
\providebool{NObib}
% \newif\ifNObib
% \NObibtrue

\ifNObib
 \def\printthebib{\relax}
\else
  \def\printthebib{\newpage\bibliographystyle{apalike}\bibliography{\jobname}}
\fi

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @ARTICLE{author,
    title={A sample article},
    author={Random Author},
    journal={Random journal},
    volume = {10},
    year = {2000},
  }
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}
As shown by \citet{author}, using references can be interesting

% \newpage
% \bibliographystyle{apalike}
% \bibliography{\jobname}
\printthebib
\end{document}
```

Compile as normal.  When you want to produce the two files, use:

```sh
pdflatex filename.tex && pdflatex --output-directory=nobibdir "\newif\ifNObib\NObibtrue\input{filename}"
```

(Where `nobibdir` is the subdirectory you created. The no-bib version of the PDF will be put there.)

One word of warning: you must remove the `.aux` file generated in the output directory. Otherwise, on a subsequent run, the bibliographic information will be lost.  Maybe something like:

```sh
pdflatex filename.tex && pdflatex --output-directory=nobibdir "\newif\ifNObib\NObibtrue\input{filename}" && rm -v nobibdir/filename.aux
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. It was a toss up between your solution and that proposed by Harish Kumar. The other solution works better simply because I can create two files in the same directory.

Comment: No problem.  When I was still sure `--jobname` would get the job done, I liked the answer more.  I thought about a `Makefile` that would then `mv` the file back into the working directory, but it started to feel like a Rube Goldberg machine....